# Intercepted form submit generates a blocking ajax request on jQuery and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

currently I'm experiencing a VERY strange problem. I've a single page application and all form submits are intercepted via:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function (e) { 
    $.ajax({ ... }) 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
});
```

On some parts on the website I've actions, which will trigger two requests. A long running one and a reoccurring one to check the state of the long running request (a little bit outdated, but I had my reasons). This is working fine.

However this will not work im combination with my form submit handler.

Working example:

```
var checker = function() {
    $.ajax(/*check the state*/).done(function() {
        setTimeout(checker(), 750);
    });
};

$.ajax(//long running request);
checker();
```

Not working example:

```
var checker = function() {
    $.ajax(/*check the state*/).done(function() {
        setTimeout(checker(), 750);
    });
};

$('#my_form').submit();
checker();
```

In this case the ajax request in the submit handler will block all other requests until done. Has anyone an explanation for this? All controllers involved in this process are decorated with:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `$(document).on('submit', ...` instead `$("body").on('submit', ...`.

Comment: This changed nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it! In fact

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

had no effect because we used a custom controller factory. Unfortunately we had overwritten only the method GetControllerInstance() to resolve our controller type from the query string, not GetControllerType(). Due to this issue the method GetSessionStateBeavoir() always returned SessionStateBehavior.Default as the Type given to the method has been null, and follwoing check is included in the original implementation of DefaultControllerFactory:

```
if (controllerType == null) {
    return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
}
```

So I've moved our logic to determine the controller type to GetControllerType() and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Could somebody explain the downvote?I think it is helpful to know that you should override GetControllerType() and not only GetControllerInstance() in order to prevent such side effects.